# How to replace string in html

Tags: jquery

In my project, I fetch html content from DB with ajax. And I want rightd replace leftd of someone's div class. And my only Judgment condition is the name of John. If i set nameCst="John", How to set the div  before John class="rightd"

```
var nameCst="John";
$.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_ajax_csc.php",
        data:{stNum:stNum},
        success:function(data) 
        {
         var beforeReplace=data.stPrc;
         //the div class of before nameCst John be replaced to rightd
         //after repalce, 
         $('#timeTagDiv').html(afterReplace);
        }
    });
```

Before replace, the content of beforeReplace :

```
<div class="leftd">
    <label id="dlgRspTime">10:23:40</label>
    &nbsp;
    <label id="dlgCharge">Snow</label>
    <label>&nbsp;acceptSheet</label>
</div>
<div class="leftd">
    <label id="dlgRspTime">10:23:55</label>
    &nbsp;
    <label id="dlgCharge">John</label>
    <label>&nbsp;hangSheet</label>
</div>
```

After replace, the content of afterReplace:

```
<div class="leftd">
    <label id="dlgRspTime">10:23:40</label>
    &nbsp;
    <label id="dlgCharge">Snow</label>
    <label>&nbsp;acceptSheet</label>
</div>
<div class="rightd">
    <label id="dlgRspTime">10:23:55</label>
    &nbsp;
    <label id="dlgCharge">John</label>
    <label>&nbsp;hangSheet</label>
</div>
```

Who can give me help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me give you a quick recommendation, you shouldn't have the same 'id' attribute in different elements, change it for classes if you can. The purpose of the 'id' attribute is to be unique in your DOM.

**CHANGING CLASS AFTER SHOWING THE CONTENT**

About your question, one option is to change the class inmediatly after you put the content, so you can manipulate it directly in the DOM. If you can work with that, first you have to put...

```
$('#timeTagDiv').html(data.stPrc);
```

... and the you have two options:

1. If you know that the names are not going to match in diferent labels (even as substrings), a fast way is using :contains(). In your case, you can select and replace the class you mention in one line...

   ```
   var nameCst='John';
   $('label:contains('+nameCst+')').parent().attr('class','rightd');
   ```
2. If is posible that you have the same name as substrings in other labels ('John Smith' in one and 'John Wick' in another), then you have to go with and exact match, and I'll use filter(). In your case...

   ```
   var nameCst='John';

   $("label").filter(function() {
       return $(this).text() === nameCst;
   }).parent().attr("class", "rightd");
   ```

If you have some kind of visualization problem doing things in this order (the content moves in a blink or something "ugly" like that), just hide the container first, put the content inside, change the class and then show the container.

**CHANGING CLASS BEFORE SHOWING THE CONTENT**

Anyway, if for some reason you need to change the html before loading the context, you can go like this...

```
var nameCst='John';

var $myHtml = $(data.stPrc);

// Use contains() or filter() depending or your case. Here I use contains...        
$myHtml.find('label:contains('+nameCst+')').parent().attr('class','rightd');

$('div#timeTagDiv').html($myHtml);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: lglesias, as you said, I have same name as substring. So i chose filter(), like $myHtml.find('label:filter(function(){return $(this).text()=='+stChr+';}').parent().attr('class', 'rightd');But it failed

Comment: Like in the contains version, first you have to use find() and then filter(), not :filter...

    $myHtml.find("label").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === nameCst;
    }).parent().attr("class", "rightd");

Comment: @stack In case you need it, here you have a Fiddle example...

https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/avunnb3j/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to give the one to be replaced an ID, so you can look after it in `jQuery`

```
<div class="leftd">
    <label id="dlgRspTime">10:23:40</label>
    &nbsp;
    <label id="dlgCharge">Snow</label>
    <label>&nbsp;acceptSheet</label>
</div>
<div class="leftd" id="toBeReplaced">
    <label id="dlgRspTime">10:23:55</label>
    &nbsp;
    <label id="dlgCharge">John</label>
    <label>&nbsp;hangSheet</label>
</div>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
$("#toBeReplaced").addClass("rightd").removeClass("leftd")
```

Edited: You can use `$(this)` to select the exact instance you are clicking

```
$("#leftd").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("rightd").removeClass("leftd");
})
```

You can use this snippet to create something more complicated

Comment: ， The only judgement condition is the name. If I choose John, the second div class set to righted. If i choose Snow, the first div calss set to rightd

Comment: sorry to confuse you, I have update my content and code

Comment: @stack You can actually replace the entire inner content with `html()` function in jquery. The only thing you need to do here would be place your content as a string

Comment: i just want to replace class="leftd" before place my content as a string.